# Rcpp Basic Numeric Matrix Example Error

Tags: r, rcpp

I am currently trying to figure out how to use Rcpp and have been going through the examples listed at [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) website. I've been able to get through all the examples up until the examples involving matrices. For example, the following code has been giving me trouble. I've separated the code into a .r file listed below

```
# rcpp_test.r     

require( Rcpp )


test<-function(x){

    cppFunction('NumericVector rowSumsC(NumericMatrix x) {

      int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();

      NumericVector out(nrow);

      for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {

        double total = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
          total += x(i, j);
        }

        out[i] = total;
      }

      return out;
   }')  

   return(rowSumsC(x))
}
```

Now when I do the following I get an error message

```
> source('rcpp_test.r')
   Loading required package: Rcpp
> x <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), byrow=T, nrow=3)
> test(x)
   Error in rowSumsC(x) : 
 INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL'
```

Not sure where this: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL' error is coming from which is sad because getting the NumericMatrix object to work would be pretty cool. Any help or advice would be appreciated

Edit:

I have included sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.11.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: This code runs for me, can you post your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I don't get any error neither. Did you try running without sourcing it? Just straight after you defined the function in the Global env?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that and am getting the same error. Maybe there's something wrong with RStudio or I'm using too new a version of Rcpp. I just downloaded everything like two days ago (ie R Studio, Rcpp).

Comment: I have the same Rcpp version so its not it. Maybe try to close and reopen and run this from a fresh session. Otherwise I'm out of ideas

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I wish it was that simple! This looks like it might bug me for a while

Comment: Why did you put it inside additional function anyway? You can just call it using `rowSumsC(x)`. If you don't like the name, then change it while defining the function `cppFunction('NumericVector test(NumericMatrix x) {...`

Comment: Very true. I'm just in the habit of putting things in a separate file. Either way works I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I place your code into a file `/tmp/rowSumC.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rowSumsC(NumericMatrix x) {
  int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out(nrow);

  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
      total += x(i, j);
    }
    out[i] = total;
  }
  return out;
}
```

then things work just fine:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/rowSumC.cpp")
R> rowSumsC(matrix(1:9,3))
[1] 12 15 18
R>
```

This would presumably work the same way via `cppFunction()` which I tend to reserve for really short functions of one or two lines.

Comment: I still got the same error in a Windows environment, but since everybody else said the same code worked I tried it on a Mac and it worked! This maybe a Windows thing. Oh well, I will work in Unix-Like environments from now on. Thanks